# Why won't this print a value in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
class Some {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int one = 77; one ==  0; --one) {
      if(one == 77) {
        System.out.println("Original integer:" + one);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Integer: " + one);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused as to why the code is unable to print the values. I'd appreciate if someone would tell me how I could get the loop to work successfully. Help is appreciated since this is my first attempt at Java. Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? explicitly, What do you expect the first and last output to be?

Comment: I clearly stated that 'the code is unable to print the values' which probably implies I need help getting the values to print. There was no need to give me a downvote for that.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach That really shouldn't matter if OP just wants to get the loop to do _something_ (_anything_) first -- fixing the last output is a separate issue. OP's just learning, and learning happens one step at a time.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. I was asking for clarification to provide a full answer :-)

Comment: OT: `one` is not a good name for a variable, especially not if its value is not 1.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Sorry, that's my bad.

Comment: @Henry Honestly, I just named it randomly because I just wanted to see how a for-loop worked, I didn't realize an error would occur.

Comment: @Flamentix Naming the variable `one` is just a bad _stylistic_ choice but it doesn't cause your errors.

Comment: @pkpnd Yeah, I know. What I basically meant is that I thought that I would make the program and get rid of it, so variable name wouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *for* loop testing condition is false to begin with (`one == 0`). You should have meant `one >= 0` or `one > 0` as the for loop testing condition.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. However, when I attempt to compile the code, it returns no syntax errors, but it doesn't print any value.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, turned out I accidentally changed the sign from '==' to '>' rather than '<'

Answer (score 3):

Your loop does not run because `one` is not 0 at the beginning. The loop runs as long as the condition is true.

Your condition should be `one >= 0` instead or if you don't want the loop to run for one == 0 make it `one > 0`.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Downvotes are your prerogative but I think it's excessive to downvote a majority of the answers here for that triviality. All of those answers get at the _primary_ problem, which is that the OP doesn't understand how to use for loop conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code such that the program enters at least once inside the **for loop**. Since you initialized i=77, when condition one==0 is checked it is found false. So the program won't enter inside the for loop and hence nothing will be printed.

```
class Some 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        for(int one = 77; one>=0; --one) 
        {
            if(one == 77) 
            {
                System.out.println("Original integer:" + one);
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Integer: " + one);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I've stated on other posts, you have offered the termination without showing the output, or explaining when the loop stops when the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

`one == 0`is never true hence loop wont run

You want to do `one > 0`

in your loop as :

```
for(int one = 77; one >  0; --one) {
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

States that the for statement is split into 3 parts.

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

the initialization, the termination and the increment.

Your for loop has

initialization as `int one = 77;`

termination as `one ==  0;`

and the increment as `--one`

it further states

"When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates."

this means that `one` will start at 77, and decrement each loop, **while** one is equal to zero.

so simply change your termination to be true until it hits zero, or true until it's past zero depending on the behavior you need.